# Sending Case Reply Email With Proper Reply-To in SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, email, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have some functionality that automatically sends an email response when a case is created via someone submitting an email that gets sent to a NetSuite case profile email address. The trouble comes when attempting to set a proper reply-to email address. So far the attempts at creating one don't allow for a successful response directly back into the case record. At first undeliverable messages were being returned until I found an error made in the structure of the address. Now, however, the messages don't appear to make it back to the case records. This is the structure being used:

```
cases.AAAAA.BBBBB_CCCCC_DDDDD.EEEEE@AAAAA.email.netsuite.com
// AAAAA is the account number
// BBBBB is the internal ID of the case record
// CCCCC is the internal ID of the message record
// DDDDD is the internal ID of the customer record on the case
// EEEEE is a hexadecimal value of unknown sourcing or meaning
```

I'm thinking maybe part of the problem is that the message record ID is the ID of the message that was sent out from the case, and with what I've been doing it's the ID of the message record saved from the initial incoming email that generated the case in the first place. This leads me to believe that I can't just use the email.send() API with setting a reply-to email address, but I don't see another way to send out the email. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use the `email.send()` function if you intend on having the customer be able to reply to a Support Case.

Instead, you need to create a Case record (or load an existing one) and then send your email message through that Case record.

Upload the following example script to your File Cabinet and create a Suitelet script, deploy it, and run it. You'll see a simple form that allows you to send out an email via a Case record.

**EXAMPLE SCREENSHOT:**
[image: Suitelet to send case email message]

**CODE:**

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/ui/message', 'N/record', 'N/url', 'N/email'], function (serverWidget, message, record, url, email) {
    function onRequest(context) {

        var form = serverWidget.createForm({
            title: 'Send Email via Support Case'
        });
        form.addField({
            id: 'custom_customer',
            label: 'Customer',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
            source: record.Type.CUSTOMER
        });
        form.addField({
            id: 'custom_email',
            label: 'Email Address (not required)',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT
        });
        form.addField({
            id: 'custom_messagesubject',
            label: 'Message Subject',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT
        });
        form.addField({
            id: 'custom_messagebody',
            label: 'Message Body',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.RICHTEXT
        });
        form.addSubmitButton({
            label: 'Send Email'
        });

        if (context.request.method === 'POST') {
            var customerId = context.request.parameters['custom_customer'];
            var customerEmail = context.request.parameters['custom_email'];
            var messageSubject = context.request.parameters['custom_messagesubject'];
            var messageBody = context.request.parameters['custom_messagebody'];

            try {
                var caseId = 0;
                var errorMsg = '';

                var caseRec = record.create({
                    type: record.Type.SUPPORT_CASE
                });
                caseRec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'company',
                    value: customerId
                });
                // You can specify an email address to overide the customer's default
                // Useful if you need to use an "Anonymous Customer" record and set the outgoing email address to the correct one
                if (customerEmail != '') {
                    caseRec.setValue({
                        fieldId: 'email',
                        value: customerEmail
                    });
                }
                caseRec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'title',
                    value: messageSubject
                });
                caseRec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'emailform',
                    value: true
                });
                caseRec.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'outgoingmessage',
                    value: messageBody
                });
                caseId = caseRec.save({
                    ignoreMandatoryFields: true
                });

            } catch (e) {
                errorMsg = JSON.stringify(e);
            }

            if (caseId > 0 && errorMsg == '') {
                var caseUrl = url.resolveRecord({
                    recordType: record.Type.SUPPORT_CASE,
                    recordId: caseId
                });
                form.addPageInitMessage({
                    message: 'Email sent successfully. <a target="_blank" href="' + caseUrl + '">Open Support Case</a>',
                    title: "Success!",
                    type: message.Type.CONFIRMATION
                });
            } else {
                form.addPageInitMessage({
                    message: "Error occurred while sending case message: " + errorMsg,
                    title: "Failed",
                    type: message.Type.ERROR
                });
            }

        }

        context.response.writePage(form);
    }
    return {
        onRequest: onRequest
    };
});
```

Comment: Yeah, didn't really need a form with this, since the process was being handled automatically during a User Event script, but I did forget that this was a thing that could be done with case records. Thank you.

Comment: The form was just to help to give people a full understanding of how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the relatedRecords.activityId will automatically send the email with case reply to address.

```
                email.send({
                    author: me.id,
                    recipients: you.id,
                    subject: 'New Case',
                    body: emailBody,
                    // attachments: [fileObj],
                    relatedRecords: {
                        activityId: thisCase.id
                    }
                });
```